# SCSS broken by vue.config.js css.extract

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli-3

Running a Vue CLI project.

Today my SCSS stopped reloading automatically.

After some digging, it seems like part of the `vue.config.js` is causing the problem. Here is my config:

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        data: `@import "@/assets/styles/abstracts.scss";`
      }
    },
    extract: {
      filename: '[name].css',
      chunkFilename: '[id].css'
    }
  },
    configureWebpack: {
        output: {
            filename: '[name].js',
            chunkFilename: '[name].js'
        }
    }
};
```

Specifically, if I comment out these few lines it solves the problem:

```
extract: {
    filename: '[name].css',
    chunkFilename: '[id].css'
}
```

I don't think this was happening before, but its possible it was. In any case, this code is kind of important because I need my production files to not include hashes. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: what you mean by  "I need my production files to not include hashes" ?

Comment: @mooga with out these config settings the output files are like this: app.573h73g4.css app.4937764hg.js vendor.837fhdk2.js.

Comment: With this config the random alphanumeric hash is removed from the production files.